# Group Action on $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $n$ elements and  $\sigma \in S_n$ be a permutation. One can represent $\sigma$ (essentially uniquely) as a set of $m$ disjoint
cycles of lengths $l_1,l_2,\dots,l_m$  such that these cycles partition the set of $n$ objects.

Does there exist a (non-trivial) group $G$ that acts (non-trivially) on $S_n$ that preserves the number of disjoint cycles and their respective lengths? I.e. does there exist a group, $G$,
such that for any $g \in G$ if a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ can be represented by a set of $m$ disjoint cycles of lengths $l_1,l_2,\dots,l_m$ then the permutation, $g \cdot \sigma$,  can similarly be represented as a set of $m$ disjoint cycles of lengths $l_1,l_2,\dots,l_m$?

Comment: Sure, $S_n$ itself, acting by conjugation.